# ListView, with 3 text columns, onClick listener is not working

Tags: android, onclick, listitem

I have a `ListView` which include 3 columns of `TextView`, I am trying to working when selecting a row to do action, so I started experimenting by using `Toast` message, but nothing is showing, please can someone help.

```
    public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDB;
ArrayList<User> userList;
ListView listView;
User user;
TextView firstName;
TextView lastName;
TextView favFood;
MediaPlayer player;
private int featureCustomTitle;
ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
    TextView lastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
    TextView favFood = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);
    ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
    int numRows = data.getCount();
    if (numRows == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "The Database is empty  :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            user = new User(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3));
            userList.add(i, user);
            System.out.println(data.getString(1) + " " + data.getString(2) + " " + data.getString(3));
            System.out.println(userList.get(i).getFirstName());
            i++;
        }

    }
  
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item Name is " + listView.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you should do this stuff in your custom listview adapter

Comment: I have loaded the full code, please can you check @OMiShah

Comment: Now it is working, it seems I need to make false for focusable :)